# C#のリストでの文字列検索について

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
C#での文字列検索を行いたいと考えています。
下記のようなリストを想定しています。

```
List<string> file_list = new List<string>();
file_list.Add("data/test01.txt");
file_list.Add("data/test02.txt");
file_list("data/test03.dat");
file_list.Add("data/test04.dat");
```

とりあえず、FindAll等で文字列を指定して検索できることはわかったんですが、ファイル名のワイルドカード（「data/*.txt」のようなもの）にマッチする要素を取り出すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。
ちなみに、マッチする要素1つだけではなく、マッチするすべての要素を取得したいと考えています。
何かアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に対応する正規表現に変換して検索してみるとか。[Windows のワイルドカード文字列を正規表現に変換するメソッド](https://qiita.com/AsladaGSX/items/5d109cdfb9519e142ad3), [ワイルドカードを使用した文字列マッチ](https://qiita.com/kazuhirox/items/5e314d5e7732041a3fe7), [Need to perform Wildcard (*,?, etc) search on a string using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6907720/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントで紹介した３つのうち、最初の記事は色々と変なので忘れてください。

3つ目の英語版StackOverflowの記事が短くて良さそうです。
 [Need to perform Wildcard (*,?, etc) search on a string using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6907720/9014308)
さらにオリジナルはこちらのようですが。
[Converting Wildcards to Regexes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes)

コピーしておくと：

> ```
> public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
> {
>     return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern)
>                       .Replace(@"\*", ".*")
>                       .Replace(@"\?", ".")
>                + "$";
> }
> ```

上記を使って`FindAll()`のパラメータにすれば、こんな風に出来ます。

```
// 検索パターンの正規表現を作成
Regex RegexWild = new Regex(WildcardToRegex("data/*.txt"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// 文字列のリストで取得
List<string> ListResult = file_list.FindAll(s => RegexWild.IsMatch(s));

// 文字列の配列で取得
string[] ArrayResult = file_list.FindAll(s => RegexWild.IsMatch(s)).ToArray();
```

---

**追記**
取り敢えずパス＆ファイル指定時との互換性を高めたものを作ってみました。
突っ込みどころは色々あるでしょうが、今のところはこれまで。
ただ、それらを考えるとコメントで紹介した最初の記事は、それなりに合理的だったのかもしれません。

```
// ワイルドカードを使用したパスから正規表現へ
// From Path with Wildcard To Regex
public static string PathWildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
    string work = "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern)
                      .Replace(@"\*", ".*")
                      .Replace(@"\?", ".")
               + "$";
    work = Regex.Replace(work, @"(\\\\|/)", @"[\\/]"); // 区切り記号に'/'と'\'の両方を許す
    work = work.Replace(@".*\..*", @".*");             // '*.*'は'*'に変える
    work = work.Replace(@".*\.[\\/]", @"[^.]+[\\/]");  // Path途中の'*.'の処理
    work = work.Replace(@".*\.$", @"[^.]+$");          // Path最後の'*.'の処理
    return work;
}
```

Comment: Windowsの場合、`/` と `＼` がディレクトリ区切りとして認められているので、必要であればその辺りもケアしたほうがいい場合もあります。`/`で統一されている場合は不要ですが。それとこれもWindows限定ですが、`*.*`が拡張子なしにもマッチする仕様もあるので、こちらも必要であれば。

Comment: 一応バックスラッシュは処理の最初で使っている[Regex.Escape(String) メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8)で対処されているようです。他にも追加の要件があれば、その時々の使用目的に合わせて調整が必要ということですね。

Comment: Windowsの場合 `data/test01.txt` に対して `data\*.txt` でもマッチするので、そういう対処も必要かもしれないということです。

Comment: なるほど、`dir`コマンド等のパラメータ仕様との互換性をどれだけ高めるか、ですね。たしかに今はその辺は考慮していない汎用的な処理ですね。質問者さんの要求水準がどれくらいかによるところですかね。

Comment: なるほど、正規表現に変換する必要があったんですね。いただいたコードでうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。